# What is the difference between = and == in Pharo Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

What is the difference between `=` and `==` in Pharo Smalltalk? What are they named, one `isEqual` and the other?

```
= ~=    equality / inequality (deep)
== ~~   equality / inequality (shallow)
```

Comment: `=` refers to *equality* (objects are equal in value) and `==` refers to *identity* (objects are identical). See [Equality versus Identity](http://esug.org/data/HistoricalDocuments/TheSmalltalkReport/ST05/10wo.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

One important thing to take into account is that `=` is not only used explicitly when your code compares two objects. The message `=` is also *implicitly* used by many other messages such as: `includes:`, `<=`, `>=`, `remove:`, `keyAtValue:`, `indexOf:`, `upTo:`, `peekFor:`, `occurrencesOf:`, `add:` (in `Set`), `at:` (and friends `at:ifAbsent:`, `at:ifAbsentPut:`, etc.), and many others.

This means that when you redefine `=` in your class you should make sure that

1. Your implementation of `=` is robust (e.g., `banana = car` gives no error) and
2. Every time you redefine `=` you also redefine `hash`.

The reason for the first condition is to be able to compare any two objects without the sender having to take any special care before sending the `=` message.

The reason for the second is that if in the future your objects are used in a hashed collection (`Set`, `Dictionary`, `Bag`, etc.) they will honor the important invariant required by these entities

```
      IF a = b THEN a hash = b hash
```

And given that it is a very good practice to make sure that `hash` values are `SmallIntegers`, one could say

```
      IF a = b THEN a hash == b hash
```

In other words, every time two objects are considered to be *equal* their `hash` values should be granted to be *identical*.

---

**Naming**

When reading an expression involving `=` such as `a = b` one says `a` *is equal to* `b` or `a` *equals* `b`.

When reading `a == b` Smalltalkers say `a` *and* `b` *are the same object*, or `a` *is identical to* `b` or even `a` *is equal-equal to* `b`.

**Further comments**

The `=` message is domain specific, meaning that it is up to you to decide when two Smalltalk objects represent the very same object in your application.

The `==` message is a system feature, meaning that it is implemented by the Virtual Machine (VM) which verifies that the objects being compared occupy the very same location in memory. In other words, two variables `a` and `b` are *equal-equal* when they are bound to the very same object.

**Examples**

```
a := 'This String'.
b := 'This' , ' ', 'String'.
a == b "false".
a = b "true"

f := 2 / 3.
g := 2 / 3.
f = g "true".
f == g "false"
```

Generally speaking `SmallInteger`s which are `=` are also `==` because the VM encodes them in a special way.

```
n := 3 + 4.
m := 2 + 5.
n = m "true".
n == m "true".
```

Another interesting case happens with instances of the class `Symbol`

```
s := #symbol.
t := 'symbol' asSymbol.
s = t "true".
s == t "true!"
```

This happens because the `Symbol` class makes sure that no two instances with the same underlying string will ever exist in the environment.

Comment: What about naming? One "is equal to" the other "is same as" or "is identical to"?

Comment: @unmircea `=` means "is equal to" or "has the same value as". `==` means "is identical to" or "is the same object as".

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `==` is identity and it uses a primitive to compare if pointers point to the same address (i.e. same object).

`=` is equality, meaning that two objects are equal, although they may be 2 different objects. By default `=` uses `==`, but it can be reimplemented. Also when you reimplement `=` it's advised to also reimplement `hash` so hashed collections won't go crazy

Comment: What about naming? One "is equal to" the other "is same as" or "is identical to"?

Comment: @unmircea I think it is equal and identical, but usually I use "equal" and for `==` I say: _check if it is the same object_

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: = : "equals", == : "same as"

In Object>>#=

```
= anObject 
"Answer whether the receiver and the argument represent the same 
object. If = is redefined in any subclass, consider also redefining the 
message hash."

^self == anObject
```

In ProtoObject>>#==

== anObject 
    "Primitive. Answer whether the receiver and the argument are the same 
    object (have the same object pointer). Do not redefine the message == in 
    any other class! Essential. No Lookup. Do not override in any subclass. 
    See Object documentation whatIsAPrimitive."

```
<primitive: 110>
self primitiveFailed
```

So, you can override = but not ==.

FWIW `ProtoObject subclass: #Object`

An example of an #= override is

´= aBag
    "Two bags are equal if
     (a) they are the same 'kind' of thing.
     (b) they have the same size.
     (c) each element occurs the same number of times in both of them"

```
(aBag isKindOf: Bag) ifFalse: [^false].
self size = aBag size ifFalse: [^false].
contents associationsDo: [:assoc|
    (aBag occurrencesOf: assoc key) = assoc value
        ifFalse: [^false]].
^true`
```

Which, compared to `Dictionary` is a quite different beast (implementation of Bas in "interesting").

`Dictionary>>#= aDictionary
    "Two dictionaries are equal if
     (a) they are the same 'kind' of thing.
     (b) they have the same set of keys.
     (c) for each (common) key, they have the same value.
    See issue 16760 before changing"

```
self == aDictionary ifTrue: [^true].
self species == aDictionary species ifFalse: [^false].
self size = aDictionary size ifFalse: [^false].
self associationsDo: [:assoc|
    (aDictionary at: assoc key ifAbsent: [^false]) = assoc value
        ifFalse: [^false]].
^true`
```

Interestingly they share the same `hash` method.

`Collection>>#hash
    "Answer an integer hash value for the receiver such that,
      -- the hash value of an unchanged object is constant over time, and
      -- two equal objects have equal hash values"

```
| hash |

hash := self species hash.
self size <= 10 ifTrue:
    [self do: [:elem | hash := hash bitXor: elem hash]].
^hash bitXor: self size hash
```

`
There is some smell with the self size <= 10, have fun tracing these calls.

For more basic objects, see these:

[image: Magnitude>>#hash implementers]

Have fun exploring.

In Spotter, `hash #im` or `= #im` gives you the implementers list, so you can quickly find out about them.

[image]

Comment: Be aware that `xor`-based hashes are generally suboptimal because they do not use bits of orders higher than the ones in the elements being `xor`ed.